# Empty interfaces - Modeling of object relationships

Tags: java, oop, interface

Is it ok to use empty interfaces for object modeling?

E.g. the following interface extends other empty interfaces in order the characterize the object 'Ferry':

```
public interface Ferry extends Watercraft, StationBased, Scheduled, Oneway, Motorized {}
```

Watercraft, StationBased, etc., are all empty interfaces, too, so they kind of act as a marker. However, they are not used by the JVM or compiler. These classes are only used for modeling purposes.
Is this good practice? Should an interface not usually provide some kind of common functionality, and not merely mark a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use empty interfaces for object modeling, but... Object modeling without any use-case is IMO overstretching it.

You write code to execute concrete actions, you model it to leverage general abstractions in the domain, and yes you can over-abstract your code.

Adding an interface in code is a classification or typification, which is only necessary as long as there is a taker for it. Otherwise it is plain dead code.

My worst encounter which sometimes still haunts me in my nightmares was an abstraction over business services, which essentially replaced it with a single method taking a map as arguments and returning an object which either contained the result or an error state. Effectively modeling a method invocation, but this time without types. Having forced this down on all business methods was simply a nightmare to unravel later.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with doing it that way except that you may discover quite quickly that changing the structure or adding new forms will become unpleasant.

I would probably consider a much more flexible `enum` option.

```
enum CraftAttributes {

    Watercraft,
    StationBased,
    Scheduled,
    Oneway,
    Motorized;
}

class Ferry {

    Set<CraftAttributes> attributes = EnumSet.of(
            CraftAttributes.Watercraft
    //...

    );

}
```

There are lots of sweet thing you can do with unions and intersections of `Set`s that make for powerful but lucid code.